# Jmeter for concurrent users

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have being using Jmeter-plugin Ultimate thread group for concurrent request.
But now I'm finding it difficult to use because the scenario is :
Each request has a trackingnumber(The trackingnumber are already generated in the system when a form is submitted, so I have to use the generated tracking number from DB) which are generated  passed as a POST in http request, these trackingnumber are unique and have configured csv config for passing the trackingnumber. So once when trackingnumber is used, it cant be used again (as it would give me a error message) . So can someone please suggest me how to stress test this scenario where I have to hit a particular URL (with unique trackingnumber from csv file) for approximately 60/30 mins (with varing no of threads) till I get the crash point of the system.

Comment: you can pass the tracking numbers via csv file.

Answer (score 0):

1st way:- 
You can pass the tracking numbers via csv file steps as,

1. allocate all the tracking numbers to specific uses (this can be possible with database query).
2. copy-paste those tracking numbers in csv file.
3. pass those tracking numbers as an parameter via csv data set config.

2nd way:-

1. fill the form & generated tracking number can be fetch via regular expression.
2. set allocation logic to specific user each time (disable other users).
3. log-in with this user & pass the fetched tracking number.

Hope will be helpful to you.